# Ordering of Magento 2 footer links

Tags: magento-2.1, footer-links

I've added and removed some of the links that come in the footer e.g. privacy policy, search terms, order etc and added some custom links but can't figure out how to order them the way I want. Currently the Magento 2.1 links sit on top of my added links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `move` directive in layout xml to move an existing link block. for example:

```
<move element="contact-us-link" destination="footer_links" after="-"/>
```

will move the contact us link to the back.